# Estimate coefficient of a general equation

Tags: python, dsolve

I have a function f(x) = a + bx + cx^2 where x is an integer and takes only positive values.
I also have a list of value of f(x) for x = 0, 1, 2,......
How do I estimate the values of a, b and c using some module in python (eg. Dsolve)

Here I want a generic module where I can define any function (f(x)) and the data set and get the values of the coefficients.
for ex. the function could be f(x) = a + bx + ce^x or anything else.

Comment: I dont know about a python library, but such problems are in general solved by the least-squares method.

Comment: Yeah I know, but I am looking for a python library that could implement the least-square method or any other method.

Comment: See http://python4mpia.github.io/fitting_data/least-squares-fitting.html -- even their **example** is a quadratic, can't get any closer to your question!-)

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex, This is exactly what I wanted.